# Filter and translating functionality for a custom map with Java 8

Tags: java

I have a task where I need to implement some functionallity to abstract methods. The idea is to use Java 8, but I'm kinda new to programming with Java 8. The following is the abstract class that I need to implement:

```
public abstract class SortedMap<K extends Comparable<K>, V> implements Iterable<Pair<K, V>>
{
    /**
     * Returns a map where all values have been translated using the function
     * <code>f</code>.
     */
     public abstract <C> SortedMap<K, C> map(Function<? super V, ? extends C> f);

    /**
     * Returns a map containing only the keys that satisfies
     * the predicate <code>p</code>.
     */
    public abstract SortedMap<K, V> filter(Predicate<? super K> p);

    // ...
}
```

What I've got so far (with Java 8) is:

```
public final class SortedMapImpl<K extends Comparable<K>, V> extends SortedMap<K,V>
{
    private final Map<K, V> map;

    private SortedMapImpl(Map<K, V> map)
    {
        this.map = new HashMap<K, V>(map);
    }

    @Override
    public <C> SortedMap<K, C> map(Function<? super V, ? extends C> f)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public SortedMap<K, V> filter(Predicate<? super K> p)
    {
        final Map<K, V> filteredMap = map.entrySet()
                                         .stream()
                                         .filter(Predicate<? super Entry<K, V>> p)
                                         .collect(Collectors.toMap(p -> p.getKey(), p -> p.getValue()));

        return new SortedMapImpl<K, V>(filteredMap);
    }

    // ...

}
```

As you can see I've got no clue at the moment how to implement the map() method, and the filter method is at least partly wrong. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

I'll help you implement the filter, and hopefully you should get the idea and implement the map by yourself.

You need to filter the entries of the original map, and only keep the ones for which the key satisifes the key predicate:

```
public SortedMap<K, V> filter(Predicate<? super K> predicate) {
    Map<K, V> filteredMap = 
        map.entrySet()
           .stream()
           .filter(entry -> predicate.test(entry.getKey()))
           .collect(Collectors.toMap(entry -> entry.getKey(), 
                                     entry -> entry.getValue()));

    return new SortedMapImpl<K, V>(filteredMap);
}
```

I would not use the name `SortedMap`, though: your map is not a map, it's not sorted either, and `SortedMap` is already a standard collection name, which will make your class confusing and cumbersome to use.

Comment: Thanks! I'm gonna try to understand your implementation of filter, and then hopefully I will be able figure out the map implementation :)

Comment: A small correction, I believe it should be 
`.filter(entry -> p.test(entry.getKey()))`
instead of
`.filter(entry -> predicate.test(entry.getKey()))`